Use WCF of .NET Framework to serialize a class as a primitive
I am using Windows Communication Foundation classes to serialize and deserialize classes to and from JSON in files via the DataContractJsonSerializer class. I know there are better ways to serialize and deserialize JSON in the .NET Framework, but I am limited to using classes that come with Windows 10.
I have a class comprised of two data members which has a standard string representation.
[DataContract]
public class Joiner
{
  public int Prefix { get; set; }

  public int Suffix { get; set; }

  public override ToString()
  {
    return $"{Prefix}.{Suffix}"
  }
}

I would like to serialize and deserialize such a class as a string literal instead of a JSON object with member fields. I could add another property tagged with [DataMember] which has a custom setter and getter to assign and extract the other properties, but I would not know how to tell WCF how to treat the class as its single member of interest.
More generally, I would like to use this same technique for other classes. Perhaps a class with a single integer member could be serialized as just the integer primitive such that a list of them could be much less verbose (and easier to edit such a file when done by hand).
When one of these classes with a primitive representation is used in an array member of another type, I could add a separate [DataMember] property with an array of the expected primitive and use its setter and getter for the translation.
[DataContract]
public class Box
{
  public Joiner[] Joiners { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Joiners")]
  public string[] JoinerStrings
  {
    get {
      var js = new string[Joiners.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < js.Length; ++i)
      {
        js[i] = Joiners[i].ToString();
      }
      return js;
    }
    set {
      var j = new Joiner[value.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < j.Length; ++i)
      {
        var ints = value[i].Split('.');
        j[i] = new Joiner{ Prefix = int.Parse(ints[0]), Suffix = int.Parse(ints[1]) };
      }
      Joiners = j;
    }
}

However, this solution is less flexible and is more verbose if such classes are used in more than one place.
Does anyone know how this might be done?  If strictly necessary to accomplish this goal, I am also open to using something other than WCF classes for JSON serialization, but I am still limited to classes provided by .NET Framework 4.8.

You can't use [tag:json.net] instead?  With Json.NET you can use either a JsonConverter or a TypeConverter to serialize Joiner as a string, see Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object for how.

The tool I am creating must build and run under Windows 10 from source against .NET Framework 4.8 without external compilers or dependencies.
I could write my own serializer if strictly needed, but I am hoping it does not come to that for my narrow use case.

Are you calling constructing your DataContractJsonSerializer directly, or is the WCF framework constructing it for you internally?  Can you set up your own DataContractJsonSerializerSettings?

I construct DataContractJsonSerializer directly.  @dbc, from your reply I was able to take a more targeted look at the WCF serialization API. I might be able to create a custom IDataContractSurrogate which will do this mapping for me.  I will try this and let you know how it works. Thank you.

You mentioned in the issue description that you need to convert to a String type.
I recommend that you use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert the transferred object data to string data.
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)


